# If variable is true within foreach loop

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, foreach

Basically I have a foreach loop like this:

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $id) {
    $qty = $_POST['qty'][$key];
    $bin_location = $_POST['bin_location'][$key];
    $pdi_required = $_POST['pdi_required'.$key][0];
    $pdi_completed = $_POST['pdi_completed'][$key];
    $serial_no = $_POST['serial_no'][$key];
    $movement_by = $_POST['movement_by'][$key];
    $date_moving = $_POST['date_of_movement'][$key];
    $special_instructions = $_POST['special_instructions_admin'][$key];
    $status = strtolower($_POST['status'][$key]);

    $sql_update = "UPDATE products SET status='$status' WHERE job_id='$id'";

    $this->db->query($sql_update);
}

if ($status == 'rejected') {
    $sql_job_update = "UPDATE jobs SET status='rejected' WHERE job_id='$id'";
} elseif ($status =='pending' || $status =='returning') {
    $sql_job_update = "UPDATE jobs SET status='pending' WHERE job_id='$id'";
} else {
    $sql_job_update = "UPDATE jobs SET status='approved'";
}
```

However, I it's the last part I am most interested in (`if ($status == whatever`). How do I get the LOWEST possible value from the foreach?

This is because I have two tables, `jobs` has a table of jobs that have been done and `products` are products that are requested within the job. If a product gets rejected for whatever reason, the whole job is a failure, therefore the job should have a status of rejected. If it's not rejected and just pending, have it as pending. If all fields are accepted, then set the job status to accepted.

All I need really is to get if a certain status was true within ANY of the occurrences in the foreach loop, and if that's true, then set status to that value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of if the job is a failure with a second variable

```
$jobStatus = 0;
foreach($_POST['id'] as $key => $id)
{
    $qty = $_POST['qty'][$key];
    $bin_location = $_POST['bin_location'][$key];
    $pdi_required = $_POST['pdi_required'.$key][0];
    $pdi_completed = $_POST['pdi_completed'][$key];
    $serial_no = $_POST['serial_no'][$key];
    $movement_by = $_POST['movement_by'][$key];
    $date_moving = $_POST['date_of_movement'][$key];
    $special_instructions = $_POST['special_instructions_admin'][$key];
    $status = strtolower($_POST['status'][$key]);

    //If any of the statuses are rejected then set
    //the job as failed, otherwise it will stay as FALSE
    if( $status == "rejected") {
        $jobStatus = 1;
    } else if( ($status == "pending" || $status == "returning") && $jobStatus != 1) {
        $jobStatus = 2;
    }

    $sql_update = "UPDATE products SET status='$status' WHERE job_id='$id'";

    $this->db->query($sql_update);
}
if ($jobStatus == 1) {
      $sql_job_update = "UPDATE jobs SET status='rejected' WHERE job_id='$id'";
} elseif ($jobStatus == 2){
      $sql_job_update = "UPDATE jobs SET status='pending' WHERE job_id='$id'";
} else {
      $sql_job_update = "UPDATE jobs SET status='approved'";
}
```

Comment: This makes perfect sense thank you! I will tick you as accepted answer in 5 minutes when it lets me.

Comment: @BeatAlex reedited my question to include the pending and returning statuses, before didnt account for those

Comment: Thank you again for your help. Have reviewed it.

Answer (score 1):

Use a separate variable which you set to false before the loop. Inside the loop, set it to true if you got that certain status.

Edit: Or, since you seem to have more than two possible status values you need to consider, set it to "approved" initially, and use a comparison function that tells you which of two status values is lower. Then, in the loop, use that function to set the global status to the minimum of itself and the current loop iteration's status.